Power BI Symantec model refresh call back api missing? don't want to do pooling for get update on data transfer?
I m working on power bi Symantec model transferring big data like 50 to 100 gb.
I want to know when my data are transferred in power workspace Symantec model .
I m referring Microsoft refresh api doc for power bi.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/refresh-dataset
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerBI.Api/
but this is not really time
It requires Pooling api calls for 50 gb or 100 gb Its not appropriate for keep pooling this api.
does any one know any ways for call back mechanism for power bi when Symantec data are actually transfer and power bi will call me and update about data are transfer  rather then I keep polling refresh api.

PowerBI doesn't have a built-in callback feature specifically for monitoring data refresh completion. However, you can get the status of dataset refresh by using the PowerBI Rest API - Datasets - Get Refresh History - REST API (Power BI Power BI REST APIs) | Microsoft Learn
This API returns the status of whether a particular refresh for dataset has been 'Completed' or 'Failed' or is 'In Progress'. But you still have to keep polling this API in order to get the status of the data refresh.
